# Why is the 3rd argument of this scanf not a pointer?

Tags: c, operators, symbols

I am trying to understand why this 3rd argument in the scanf() function needs an ampersand but not the 2nd one, without the ampersand I get an error saying "Argument 3 of scanf() is not a pointer".

```
struct person {
    int age;
    float weight;
    char name[30];
};
```

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {
       printf("Enter name of person %d and age respectively: ", i);

       // To access members of 1st struct person,
       // ptr->name and ptr->age is used

       // To access members of 2nd struct person,
       // (ptr+1)->name and (ptr+1)->age is used
       scanf("%s %d", (ptr+i)->name, &(ptr+i)->age);
   }
```

I just want to understand why that's happening and I can't really get the grasp of the arrow pointer operator as well.

Comment: What is the definition of that structure? I'm guessing you have a `char*` (already a pointer) and `int` (not a pointer).

Comment: Tip: Don't use wonky pointer math when `ptr[i]` is literally *right there*. Also `ptr` is a pretty weak name for a variable, it communicates almost nothing. It's better to have some kind of meaningful label that indicates, or hints at type.

Comment: This wasn't done by me. It was done by a teacher. I'll edit the definition of the structure in the post.

Comment: Teachers often some of the singularly *worst* code imaginable, so be sure to take all their advice with a healthy dose of skepticism.

Comment: I just can't understand why when I remove the & from the 3rd argument I get the error "Argument 3 of scanf() is not a pointer". I don't see any * in the struct so why is the 2nd argument a pointer but not the 3rd one?

Comment: Arrays (eg: `(ptr+i)->name`) decay to pointers.

Comment: How `%s` works is usually covered very early on in any beginner-level learning material. SO is not an interactive tutorial and besides this question has likely already been asked a thousand times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the pointer dereferencing, you get something akin to this:

```
int age;
char name[30];

scanf("%s %d", name, age);
```

Where clearly the `age` argument is just an `int`, and that can't be mutated.<sup>1</sup> `scanf` needs to be able to alter that, so the C convention for a mutable argument is to pass it in as a pointer, or `&age` in this case.

When extended to your original example you get `&(ptr[i]->age)`, something that can be expressed as a more relaxed `&ptr[i]->age` since both `[]` and `->` have higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `&`.

--

<sup>1</sup> Modifications to argument values are local. Modifications made via a pointer impact the original value.

Comment: This really helped in understanding how that works. Thanks a lot